# How to rename method with name existing in super class?

Tags: java, object, methods, compiler-errors, final

I want to rename my function with `notify()`, and I get compilation error with:

```
Method 'notify()' cannot override method 'notify()' in
 'java.lang.Object'; overridden method is final.
```

Can I do this? If not, why not?

Comment: `Object.notify()` is a `final` method and therefore is not overridable. can't you name your function something else?

Comment: @HamishD, yes i can, just i went to know, "why", thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not override [`Object.notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) which is `final`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot override final methods.

You can define a method with the name `notify` if you need parameters, e.g.

```
void notify(Object thing, String that) {
  // ...
}
```

Otherwise, your only option is to rename the method.

(If you wanted your name to be cursed down the ages by future users of your code, you could name your method `notıfy()`; but that would be very tricky to type without a Turkish keyboard anyway.)